# Method readLp from LPSolve library called doesn't parse float values when it is called from Java

Tags: java, linear-programming, lpsolve

I am using LPSolve from Java and I need to use a decimal constant value but it ignores the digits after the point.

**For example:**
The follow lp model (in lp format):

```
max: 0.5 x1;
r_1: x1 <= 5;
```

It has an objective function's "optimal value" of 0 because it parses the objective function as `max: 0 x1`.

I am solving the model using:

```
LpSolve solver = LpSolve.readLp("pathToModel",1,"");
solverResult = solver.solve();
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Java may set the locale for the C runtime. I would try to set the locale to US before calling LPSolve.

Comment: Erwinm thanks for your answer. I add a line    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US); before call to LPSolve but it doesn't fix the bug. Are there any other idea?